# Add onclick listener by button class name for table class referred to by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT: This jsfiddle might be easier to work with to understand the heart of my problem: [jsfiddle.net/rzdhm6xe](http://jsfiddle.net/rzdhm6xe)

I am developing a site which handles creation of events. I am using:

- Parse.js: 1.4.2
- JQuery: 1.11.2 and 1.10.3 (U.I.)
- Twitter Bootstrap: 3.3.4

I cannot post the entire html file because I am using `.hide()` and `.show()` heavily

HTML:

```
<!-- Team Settings CONTENT -->
<div id="dashboard_nav_team_settings_content">


</div><!--/ Team Settings CONTENT -->
```

The jquery is this when the above div is loaded.

```
//<TEAM SETTINGS PAGE>
        for(var i = 0; i < parseQueryList.length; i++)
        {
// how to truncate a string
            var title = '';
            title = 'Bowl: ' + parseQueryList[i].get('title');

            var team_settings_content = "";
            team_settings_content = 
                '<div class="panel panel-primary">' +
                    '<div class="panel-heading">' +
                        '<h3 class="panel-title" style="display:inline-block;">' + title + '</h3>'+
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="position:relative; display:block; float:right; bottom:5px">Email All</button>' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info  bowlManagAddPerson" style="position:relative; display:block; float:right; right: 10px; bottom:5px">Add</button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="panel-body bowlManage">' +
                        '<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">' +
                            '<table class="table table-striped table-hover bowlmanagetable">' +
                                '<thead>' +
                                    '<tr>' +
                                    '<th>First Name</th>' +
                                    '<th>Last Name</th>' +
                                    '<th>Role</th>'+
                                    '<th>Email</th>' +
                                    '<th>School</th>'+
                                    '<th>Actions</th>'+
                                    '</tr>' +
                                '</thead>' +
                                '<tbody class="team_settings_row">';

                            var row = '';
                            var firstName = '';
                            var lastName = '';
                            var object = parseQueryList[i].get("organizer");    
                            var objectTwo = parseQueryList[i].get("coach");
                            var objectThree = parseQueryList[i].get("student");
                            var coachObjects = [];
                            var studentObjects = [];
                            var role ='';
                            var outerNumber;
                            var school = '';
                            var email = '';

                            for(outerNumber = 0; outerNumber < 3; ++outerNumber)
                            {
                                role ='';
                                // ORGANIZERS
                                if(outerNumber == 0)
                                {
                                    role = 'Organizer';                             
                                }
                                // coaches
                                else if(outerNumber == 1)
                                {
                                    role = 'Coach';
                                    object =  [];
                                    object = objectTwo;
                                }
                                // students
                                else{
                                    role = 'Student';
                                    object =  [];
                                    object = objectThree;
                                }

                                var q;
                                for (q = 0; q < object.length; ++q) 
                                {                               
                                    var t;  
                                    for(t = 0; t < userQueryList.length; ++t)
                                    {
                                        if(userQueryList[t].id == object[q])
                                        {
                                            firstName = userQueryList[t].get('firstName');
                                            lastName = userQueryList[t].get('lastName');
                                            school = userQueryList[t].get('school');
                                            email = userQueryList[t].get('email');
                                            row = row + 
                                            '<tr>' +
                                                '<td>'+ firstName +'</td>' +
                                                '<td>'+ lastName +'</td>' +
                                                '<td>'+ role +'</td>' +
                                                '<td>'+ '<a href="mailto:'+ email +'?Subject=Ethics Bowl:&body=body" target="_top">'+ email +'</a>' + '</td>'+
                                                '<td>'+ school + '</td>' +
                                                '<td>' +
                                                    '<div class="btn-group">' +
                                                        '<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="text-center;">' +
                                                        '<span>Actions</span> <span class="caret"></span>' +
                                                        '</button>' +
                                                        '<ul class="dropdown-menu stay-open pull-right" role="menu" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 25px; padding-left: 50px; text-align:center;">' +
                                                            '<li><button class="btn btn-warning editManageBowl">Edit</button></li>' +
                                                            '<br>' +
                                                            '<li><button class="btn btn-danger deleteBowl">Delete</button></li>' +
                                                        '</ul>' +
                                                    '</div>' +
                                                '</td>'+
                                            '</tr>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }                               
                            var ending = '</tbody>' +
                            '</table>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';

            $('#dashboard_nav_team_settings_content').append(team_settings_content + row + ending);         
            //</TEAM SETTINGS PAGE>
        }
    });

    $('.bowlManagAddPerson').click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('1');

    });
```

What I'm stuck on is the fact that the `bowlManageAddPerson` button onclick listener is never fired within the dynamically added tables and rows. Its the bright blue button in the top right of the tables. I have no way at the moment to refer to them uniquely and have difficulty seeing a method of doing it that way within my current code.

The following is an example of what the tables would populate with. For privacy reasons, I excluded the names and emails. What I thought it would be is something involving `.closest()` but I cannot try any of that until I figure out why I can't call an onclick listener by class name for a table which has a class name.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `on` event for dynamically created elements

[Jquery On event](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#yourTABLEId').on('click', '.bowlManagAddPerson' ,function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('1');
});
```

It's actually better to use this regardless. Take into account if you had a button in every single 100 rows of your table. Instead of actually assigning the event to *EVERY* button, you assign a listener to the table, which watches for button clicks (see example above).

The `on` event is basically a listener for dynamically created object. Once your document loads, and you assign all your `click, blur, etc` events, you need this to be watching for new elements with the class or id name passed.

Comment: I appreciate your speed in answering this. I think this jsfiddle I just made is a nice example of what I was trying to explain with my original question. Its a skeleton of exactly what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/rzdhm6xe/ NOTE: it doesn't have any of the dynamic adding to rows but I can add that once I understand the lapse in logic I'm having.

Comment: You need to add jquery to fiddle - i've updated it for you - https://jsfiddle.net/rzdhm6xe/2/

Comment: I still can't getting it working on my site but I'm starting to think I have another issue somewhere in the code that is preventing this onclicklistener. I'm marking yours as best answer since the logic is sound and this should all be working.

Comment: are you receiving any console errors or is it just simply doing nothing?

Comment: I've never set up the console stuff (using notepad++ cause I'm cheap). As far as I can tell its just doing nothing. The funny thing is I basically have the exact same code on another page of my website. The only difference is that the table is loaded with a unique ID (its the only table). This page I'm working on has an unlimited number of tables and therefor I need to reference them by class, not ID. Its weird.

Comment: if you're running it in the browser you can use chrome's console. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console  - FF and IE have one as well